# Modify output format of Python logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to modify the output of my Python logger to show the process ID.

Two ways I've tried:

```
import logging
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(process)s %(thread)s: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

and

```
import logging
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(process)s %(thread)s: %(message)s"
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
handler = logger.handlers[0]
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
```

Nada. First one doesn't change the format. Second one throws an index error when I try to access `logger.handlers[0]`.

I don't want to write my own handler, just modify the format on the default handler. Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one changes format of

```
logging.<severity>("message")
```

In other words, when you set format in the first sample, you don't need to acquire separate logger instance, you can just use `logging` itself. That being said it can have unwanted effects if any other modules you're using also use `logging`.

If you want to change format of your separate logger you can use the following example:

```
from logging import StreamHandler, Formatter

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-6s %(message)s'
DATE_FORMAT = '%b %d %H:%M:%S'
formatter = Formatter(fmt=FORMAT, datefmt=DATE_FORMAT)
handler = StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: What do you have to import to get Formatter working? I have from formatter import Formatter and get  NameError: name 'Formatter' is not defined

Comment: Success! The StreamHandler recipe worked for me- thanks favoretti